# Fill in the Dashes : Part 2 of 10

Tags: english, knowledge

This is part of the [Fill in the Dashes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Fill%20in%20the%20Dashes%22) series of puzzles.

**Example:**
F_ in the B_   $\Rightarrow$  Fill in the Blanks

**Some of the words will be juxtaposed as in:**

B_ F_ in the   $\Rightarrow$  Fill in the Blanks

**Can you identify the idiom(s)/phrase(s)/proverb(s) from english language ?**

1) F_ F_ a as

2) D_ L_ L_ S_

3) F_ T_ T_ N_ W_ and

4) N_ S_ T_ S_ A in

5) B_ B_ C_ E_ T_ at

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<del>*A partial answer...*</del> 2/5 cracked by [TroyAndAbed, upvote his answer please.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17135/12700)

1. Credits to TroyAndAbed

> Fit as a fiddle

2.

> Let sleeping dogs lie

3.

> Time and tide waits for none

4.

> A stitch in time saves nine

5. Credits to TroyAndAbed

> Burn the candle at both ends

Comment: Got the 1 and 5 in my answer. Add it to yours if you want

Comment: @TroyAndABed You are quick.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Great !!!

Answer (score 10):

1)

> Fit as a fiddle

5)

> Burn the candle at both ends

Comment: Right as a Rain !!! That was quick as a Fox.